# how to Center align a whole div inside a container div using flex-box?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a layout using flex box and i've tried every combination but i'm not able to achieve what i want to have.
I want this whole "`<div class="swpm-login-widget-logged">`" to at the center of the container wihout any change in the structutre. 
Is that possible to achieve using flex-box.

Current structure: [image: Current structure]

Required structure: [image: required structure]

```css
.swpm-logged-username,
.swpm-logged-status,
.swpm-logged-membership,
.swpm-logged-expiry {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.swpm-logged-username-label,
.swpm-logged-status-label,
.swpm-logged-membership-label,
.swpm-logged-expiry-label {
  -webkit-flex-basis: 150px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 150px;
  flex-basis: 150px
}
.swpm-logged-logout-link a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #83a83d;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="swpm-login-widget-logged">
  <div class="swpm-logged-username">
    <div class="swpm-logged-username-label swpm-logged-label">Logged in as:</div>
    <div class="swpm-logged-username-value swpm-logged-value">vikrant negi</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swpm-logged-status">
    <div class="swpm-logged-status-label swpm-logged-label">Account Status:</div>
    <div class="swpm-logged-status-value swpm-logged-value">Active</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swpm-logged-membership">
    <div class="swpm-logged-membership-label swpm-logged-label">Membership:</div>
    <div class="swpm-logged-membership-value swpm-logged-value">Paid Members</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swpm-logged-expiry">
    <div class="swpm-logged-expiry-label swpm-logged-label">Account Expiry:</div>
    <div class="swpm-logged-expiry-value swpm-logged-value">Never</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swpm-logged-logout-link">
    <a href="?swpm-logout=true">Logout</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can i change your html code? or you want in this code only??

Comment: You can add any other divs or span but don't delete the current ones.

Answer (score 0):

you can add to your css

```
.swpm-login-widget-logged {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: can you add a code snippit or js fidddle for your answer. I tried but its not working, it messes up the structure.

Comment: here you go , you need also add a width for horizontal elements and I was wrong you need use flex-direction: column, jsfindle : https://jsfiddle.net/3f7ttac2/

Comment: Almost but i've to add a width to the child divs and if the length of the text inside it gets bigger the text will just wrap around. Also, i have to make width just enough big to make it center align if i increase the width the childs div doesn't center in center.

Comment: without adding width to childs element i don't think it is possible to achive that.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```css
.swpm-login-widget-logged {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    }
 .swpm-login-widget-inner {
  width: auto;
 }
  
    .swpm-logged-username,
    .swpm-logged-status,
    .swpm-logged-membership,
    .swpm-logged-expiry {
      display: -webkit-box;
      font-size: 15px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
   .swpm-logged-username-label,
   .swpm-logged-status-label,
   .swpm-logged-membership-label,
   .swpm-logged-expiry-label {
     -webkit-flex-basis: 150px;
     -ms-flex-preferred-size: 150px;
     flex-basis: 150px
   }
   .swpm-logged-logout-link a {
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 5px 15px;
     color: #fff;
     background-color: #83a83d;
     text-decoration: none;
     border-radius: 3px;
     margin-top: 15px;
   }
```

```html
<div class="swpm-login-widget-logged">
   <div class=".swpm-login-widget-inner">
     <div class="swpm-logged-username">
    <div class="swpm-logged-username-label swpm-logged-label">Logged in as:</div>
    <div class="swpm-logged-username-value swpm-logged-value">vikrant negi</div>
     </div>
     <div class="swpm-logged-status">
    <div class="swpm-logged-status-label swpm-logged-label">Account Status:</div>
    <div class="swpm-logged-status-value swpm-logged-value">Active</div>
     </div>
     <div class="swpm-logged-membership">
    <div class="swpm-logged-membership-label swpm-logged-label">Membership:</div>
    <div class="swpm-logged-membership-value swpm-logged-value">Paid Members</div>
     </div>
     <div class="swpm-logged-expiry">
    <div class="swpm-logged-expiry-label swpm-logged-label">Account Expiry:</div>
    <div class="swpm-logged-expiry-value swpm-logged-value">Never</div>
     </div>
     <div class="swpm-logged-logout-link">
    <a href="?swpm-logout=true">Logout</a>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Is there anyway i can add equal spacing on the right of the left items. If i add margin-right i have to add different margin for each element so that they can look equally align from left.

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
{
    margin:auto;
    width: 255px;
  }
```

to **.swpm-login-widget-logged**

```css
.swpm-login-widget-logged{
    margin:auto;
    width: 255px;
  }


.swpm-logged-username,
.swpm-logged-status,
.swpm-logged-membership,
.swpm-logged-expiry {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.swpm-logged-username-label,
.swpm-logged-status-label,
.swpm-logged-membership-label,
.swpm-logged-expiry-label {
  -webkit-flex-basis: 150px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 150px;
  flex-basis: 150px
}
.swpm-logged-logout-link a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #83a83d;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="swpm-login-widget-logged">
  <div class="swpm-logged-username">
    <div class="swpm-logged-username-label swpm-logged-label">Logged in as:</div>
    <div class="swpm-logged-username-value swpm-logged-value">vikrant negi</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swpm-logged-status">
    <div class="swpm-logged-status-label swpm-logged-label">Account Status:</div>
    <div class="swpm-logged-status-value swpm-logged-value">Active</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swpm-logged-membership">
    <div class="swpm-logged-membership-label swpm-logged-label">Membership:</div>
    <div class="swpm-logged-membership-value swpm-logged-value">Paid Members</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swpm-logged-expiry">
    <div class="swpm-logged-expiry-label swpm-logged-label">Account Expiry:</div>
    <div class="swpm-logged-expiry-value swpm-logged-value">Never</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swpm-logged-logout-link">
    <a href="?swpm-logout=true">Logout</a>
  </div>
</div>
```